# PayPal create payment in Django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I was reading through PayPal SDK here https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK and on PayPal website on how to add payment.

They listed four steps the first two I'm a little confused about. Handle payment client side, handle payment server side. I'm wondering how to get the response from the client side and pass it to Django view since I'm using PayPal button.